# CakePHP 2.0 Auth->user()

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to implement an ACL-Based authorization for my web-project.
I have a login method:

```
function login() {
  if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    if ($this->Auth->login()) {
      debug($this->Auth->user());
      //return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
    } else {
      $this->Session->setFlash(__('Username or password is incorrect'), 'default', array(), 'auth');
    }
  }
}
```

Instead of redirecting, I print the logged in user information. And this works well.
However, if I `debug($this->Auth->user())` in the `AppController`

```
function beforeFilter() {
  parent::beforeFilter();

  debug($this->Auth->user());

  $user = $this->Auth->user();
  if ($user) {
    $this->set('isAuthed', true);
    $this->_userId = (int) $user['User']['id'];
  } else {
    $this->set('isAuthed', false);
  }
}
```

I get nothing. What might be the problem?

Comment: Are you including the `Auth` component in `AppController`?

Comment: @Ross yes, sure. It seems that `Session` helper is not working properly. If I write something in `UsersController` with `$this->Session->write('test', test)`, I'm not able to read it in `AppController`. Any ideas?

Comment: You probably already checked that, but are cookies enabled in your browser ? If it is the case, is the value of the CAKEPHP cookie updated after each request ? (btw, in AppController you don't need to call `parent::beforeFilter()` as it is an empty method in `Controller`)

Answer (score 0):

`beforeFilter()` is executed before a normal action method, so `$this->Auth->login()` won't have been run yet. Perhaps try debugging in `afterFilter()` instead.